# A URL that links specifically to the mobile version of my site?

Tags: mobile, site-url

I (due to my participation in a certain ad network) need to provide (for a certain ad box) a link that *specifically* shows the mobile version of my site -- regardless of what device I actually am looking at the site through.

The reason is that my site is programmed to use the **wp_is_mobile()** function to determine which advertisement codes to serve. As a result, I am able to successfully activate the advertisement boxes for the desktop version of my site -- but not the mobile version.

Is there a way I can write the URL of my site that would over-ride whatever auto-detection algorithms **wp_is_mobile()** ordinarily uses so as to *specifically* force it to identify desktop or mobile mode based on the dictates of the URL?

Comment: Would be useful to see which context you're using `wp_is_mobile()`. Also, can you show a generic example of how your mobile URL looks like?